# alsaloop and bluez-alsa unstable

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, bluez

I have a raspberry pi zero w, which has a sound input via i2s (using the generic dmic driver), and connects to a bluetooth speaker using bluez5.

i set up bluez-alsa so that connected bluetooth devices are avaliable as an alsa PCM. This works and i can play files using aplay.

I can also record the input using arecord.

my requirements are now:

- record the continuous i2s input and pipe it to the bluetooth alsa output.
- the latency should be as low as possible
- the sound quality should be good.

the i2s input has a sample rate of 96khz and 32 bits, while most bluetooth speakers can handle at most a sample rate of 48khz with 16 bits.

I tried alsaloop and a combined arecord/aplay approach.

for alsaloop i used this command: `alsaloop -C i2s-input -P "bluealsa:DEV=XX" -c 2  -r96000 -fS32_LE -t 20000`

while playing with the time/buffer/period parameters i can get the delay to a pretty low value, but it is incredibly unstable. After some time i get both buffer over and underruns, and the sound starts to get weird, or fails altogether.

for arecord and aplay i tried something like `arecord -D i2s-device -c2 -r96000 -fS32_LE -traw | aplay -D "bluealsa:DEV=XX" -c2 -r96000 -fS32_LE -traw`

which worked okay, but has a pretty high delay, and a far higher cpu load than alsaloop. But I often get xruns too, and the sound breaks up.

Do your have any tips how i could inprove this setup? How exactly should the buffer/period values be set optimally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tesing i found a solution: sox

instead of using alsaloop or arecord/aplay, i set up a simple pipeline using sox:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
rec -b 32 -r 96000 --endian little -t raw -e signed-integer /tmp/pipe &
sox -b 32 -r 96000 --endian little -t raw -e signed-integer /tmp/pipe -t raw  -e signed-integer -p rate 48000 | AUDIODEV="bluealsa:DEV=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" play -b 32 -r 96000 --endian little -t raw -e signed-integer -p &
```

this creates a named pipe at `/tmp/pipe` and `rec` fills it with the input
`sox` resamples the audio data, and `play` plays it